# Post method is not updating database Django

Tags: python, django, forms, post

Post method is not updating database
Hi everyone! I’m really new in Django and python and I really need your help, please.
I need to modify one attribute (state) of an instance of my Anomalie class. I'm using forms to do that. The problem is when I “submit” to update it, I have nothing in my database. I'm following step-by-step tutorial but in my case is not working.

So here is my model class:

```
class Anomalie (models.Model):
    ANOMALIE = (
        ("Etiquette absente", "Etiquette absente"),
        ("Etiquette decalee", "Etiquette decalee"),
        ("Etiquette inconnue", "Etiquette inconnue"),
    )

    ANOMALIE_STATE = (
        ("traité", "traité"),
        ("mise à jour", "mise à jour"),
        ("signalé", "signalé"),


    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=ANOMALIE, null=False)
    date_report = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)

  
    localization = models.TextField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, choices=ANOMALIE_STATE, null=False)
  
    aisle = models.ForeignKey(Aisle, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   

    def datepublished(self):
        return self.date_report.strftime('%B %d %Y')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type
```

this is the view.py

```
def treter_anomalie(request, pk):
    anomalie_pk = Anomalie.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        anomalie_pk.state = 'traité'
        return redirect('/')

    context = {'anomalie_pk': anomalie_pk}

    return render(request, 'anomalie/treter_anomalie.html', context)
```

this is the treter_anomalie.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load static %}
{%block content%}
<div id="layoutSidenav">
    <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
        <main>
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <P>treter anomalie {{ anomalie_pk.id }}</P>

                <form action="{% url 'treter_anomalie' anomalie_pk.id %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

                    <a href="{% url 'fix_anomalie_stock' anomalie_pk.id anomalie_pk.type %}"> cancel</a>
                    <input type="submit" name="confirm">
                </form>
            </div>

        </main>

    </div>

</div>

{%endblock content%}
```

And this are urls.py

```
from anomalie.views import(
    consult_anomalie,
    fix_anomalie_stock,
    update_location_view,
    treter_anomalie,

)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_screen_view, name="home"),
    path('consult/<str:pk>/', consult_anomalie, name="consult_anomalie"),
    path('fix_anomalie_stock/<str:pk>/<str:type_anomalie>',
         fix_anomalie_stock, name="fix_anomalie_stock"),
   
]
```

So when I run the code, it returns to home page (where I have the list of Anomalies) and when I consult the specific anomalie, I see no changes.
Also, y tried `anomalie_pk.delete`, because maybe with choices is different, but it wasn't deleted.

I don’t see errors in cmd. I really don’t know what is happening, so I would appreciate your help

Comment: You dont call ```anomalie_pk.save()``` after setting the state. Second thing is, ```POST``` should be used to create new object, not updating existing one. For updates, you should use ```PATCH```

Comment: @MikołajRutecki this is submitting a form from a web page, not an API request, so POST is fine. As far as I know, you'd need to use JavaScript to submit a PATCH request from a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save the object you will need to call `save` method.

```
def treter_anomalie(request, pk):
anomalie_pk = Anomalie.objects.get(id=pk)

if request.method == "POST":
    anomalie_pk.state = 'traité'
    anomalie_pk.save() # this will save the object
    return redirect('/')

context = {'anomalie_pk': anomalie_pk}

return render(request, 'anomalie/treter_anomalie.html', context)
```

But `POST` is not used to update an object. You can create a separate view to update the object.

**EDIT**

*Creating a separate view.*

Upon closure inspection, I see that `treter_anomalie` is only used to update the object i.e. it is not used for new object. If that is the case, then you don't need to create a separate method (view). You only need to change the `method` attribute on form to `PUT` and change the if statement to `request.method == "PUT"`.

*`POST` used for creation*

As I mentioned, `POST` is used for create operation not update operation. But in practice, I have seen many time in different project use `POST` for both purposes create and update.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! :D That was exactly what I was missing! And about creating a separate view to update the object, what do you exactly mean? Do you have an example, I would love to learn. Thanks so much!